# How to create an audio streaming site in the style of Lynda or other video-training sites?

Tags: wordpress, streaming, soundcloud, shopify, audio-player

I would like to make a streaming store like Lynda.com, Udemy.com, or other video-training websites - where the customer can buy and/or subscribe to my digital library, but the customer can only stream the content, no downloading. Is this something I should do in WordPress, Shopify, or something else? A key aspect would be the customer being able to go back-and-forth between buying an individual stream and a monthly subscription without losing their purchased streams.

The content will be self-created audio files. As far as the audio-player, I was thinking about using SoundCloud.com and privatizing the audio on SoundCloud.com. Then embed the audio onto the site to prevent pirating and rely on a third-party site to host the audio content rather than burdening the hosting provider. Or is there a better solution?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN use Wordpress, but there will need to be more involved then just setting up a basic website. You'll need to provide the user with a unique URL to stream the content from.

Other than building a custom platform, you can use something like http://buddypress.org/ to create user profiles. And only allow paid users to access certain content.

Shopify will only help with taking orders. Not giving users account access to login.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! With regards to providing the user with a unique URL to stream the content from, would having the streamed content on a password protected WordPress page work? Where the user buys access to the page? I haven't heard about BuddyPress. Thank you for mentioning it. I see BuddyPress is the plugin for user's creating an account on my website, but does it extend to paid access of certain content or would that require a shopping cart plugin?

Comment: There are many was to go about this. Yes you can set a password on the page but how will you handle multiple users. You can have a user set up a WP account or buddypress profile and not approve them until they sign up via PayPal. There are tons of way. Including a custom application. But that's another question

Comment: By the way. Instead of saying "thank you" you can vote the answer UP :)

Comment: Thanks again for your response! Unfortunately, I don't have enough "reputations" to vote the answer up, so I check-marked it

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use shopify, then build out a user login side using something like Heroku. We had a similar goal to build a marketplace for live music bookings - basically the difference here being that the artists were the users, not the customers. We used Collections as profiles and Products as bookable packages. We simply embedded youtube vids and made sure to turn off recommendations in the youtube embed code. We currently make this information public, but it could be behind a login (the basic login/account that shopify provide) in your instance. It would be a little bit manual: e.g. they 'purchase' the subscription, then they create a login at checkout, whereby they're then able to access the videos/audio.
Have a play with our marketplace as an example of what I mean: [tremolo.com.au](http://www.tremolo.com.au)